# Understanding proof of Mean Value property for Harmonic Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

In the proof of the mean value property for Harmonic functions, one often sees steps such as
$$ E(r) := \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} u  \ dy = \frac{1}{|\partial B(0,1)|}\int_{\partial B(0,1)} u(x+rz)  \ dz $$
which is justified by the change of coordinates $y = x+rz$.
The second equality allows one to compute the derivative of the integral w.r.t. $r$, and after applying inverse change of variables we obtain
$$ E'(r) =  \frac{1}{|\partial B(0,1)|}\int_{\partial B(0,1)} z \cdot Du(x+rz)  \ dz = \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{x-y}{r} \cdot Du(y)  \ dy \; .$$
From which the mean value property follows easily.

On the other hand, I have attempted to obtain the the mean value property through a similar change of variable, namely $y = rz$. This changes the integral to
$$ E(r) = \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,1)|}\int_{\partial B(x,1)} u(rz)  \ dz $$
which differentiates to yield
$$ E'(r) = \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,1)|}\int_{\partial B(0,1)} z \cdot Du(rz)  \ dz = \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{y}{r} \cdot Du(y)  \ dy \; .$$
(where in the second equality I have again used the inverse change of variables). From this, it follows that we should have
$$ \int_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{x-y}{r} \cdot Du(y)  \ dy = \int_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{y}{r} \cdot Du(y)  \ dy \; .$$
Which does not seem correct. I was looking for any guidance on where I have made a mistake.

Comment: This change of variables does not go from $B(x,1)$ to $B(x,r)$. You have scaled the entire vector. For example, think in $1$ dimension. If $B(2,2)$ is the interval $(0,4)$. If you then let $y = 2z$, $z$ sweeps out the interval $(0,2)$ not $(1,3)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I guess the problem with this new change of variables is that the domain would still depend on $r$ in some way, correct?